# Can't get a bash to work with python on a SGE

Tags: bash, python, gridengine

I'm currently working on a SGE and I'm extremely unfamiliar with the linux environment. 
I have to execute python scripts but the setup is kinda confusing for me and I can't get it to work.

The setup is the following : 
The default python installed is the 2.4 and I need to use the 2.7 with some libraries.

I then linked all I needed with these lines :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
export PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/home/volatile/xxx/src/scikit-learn:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then if I type these lines and call `python test.py` it executes my code and it links everything great.

Then if I try to make a bash script (eligible for to send to the SGE) it won't work

```
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ -N JOB_TKO
#$ -l h_vmem=1000M
#$ -l h_rt=864000
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -cwd

unset SGE_ROOT

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
export PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/home/volatile/xxx/src/scikit-learn:$PYTHONPATH

python test.py
```

It won't even work if I removed the lines related to SGE and I do `$ bash job.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
export PATH=/home/volatile/xxx/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/home/volatile/xxx/src/scikit-learn:$PYTHONPATH

python test.py
```

If someone could make me understand why it doesn't work that would be really great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bash` script has DOS line endings, but `bash` expects Unix-style line endings (just a line-feed, not a carriage-return/line-feed pair. You'll need to remove them; `dos2unix` is  a good tool to use, as it `tr -d '\r'`.

Specifically, it appears the error message comes from

```
python test.py
```

since `bash` takes the carriage return following the `y` in `test.py` as part of the file name. The "real" error message consists of the bytes

```
python: can't open file 'test.py\r': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

but the `\r`, when displayed at the terminal, causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, so that the rest of the error message starting at `': [Errno 2]...` overwrites the preceding part, producing as you saw

```
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Woaw thank you. I would never have found that on my own!